# How can I create a android swipe up menu? Please refer to the attached images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, user-interface

I want my home screen to look like this

[image]

When i click on the center button or swipe up a menu should appear

[image: image2]

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this library in GitHub.

> SlideUp is a small library that allows you to add sweet slide effect
>   to any view. Slide your views up, down, left or right with SlideUp!

https://github.com/mancj/SlideUp-Android

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to animated the layout from bottom to top on the click of a button 
layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/click"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="click"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="#313131"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity {
RelativeLayout layout;
Boolean isAnimated = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);

    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!isAnimated){
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Sample.this, R.anim.translate_animation_top));
                isAnimated = true;
            }else {
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Sample.this, R.anim.translate_animation_bottom));
                isAnimated = false;
            }

        }
    });
}}
```

Animation file:

translate_animation_bottom:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

translate_animation_top:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```